# Effect in aggregated dataset

Tags: statistical-significance

For a paper, I ran four studies for which all studies provide a null effect (non-significant) in terms of a simple main effect estimate. All studies are sufficiently powered (a priori) given a within subjects design with RT as a dependent measure. If I aggregate the datasets into a single dataset and run the same analysis with study as a grouping factor I do get a significant simple main effect irrespective of study.

From what I've read it seems that high-powered estimates are better (of course) given that multiple low-powered single studies tend to include false positives. However, single studies in my sample do not signal significant results and are properly powered. What does the aggregate data add and is this necessarily more reliable than the estimates of all single studies?